# Why Are My CoreData Objects Not Being Retrieved By My View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

So I have this `xCode` project I am working on to make an iPhone app in the `Swift` language. I am trying to store two strings an a binary data image in an object in core data that I can retrieve in this `viewcontroller`. The table view that I use to transition to this view is showing the correct item associations but when I load this view the attributes don't load in. Why is the object not being uploaded and displayed to the `viewcontroller` ?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class IndividualMainViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var backCancelButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveEditButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var deviceImageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraImageButton: UIButton!


    var item: Item? = nil
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()


    @IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var horseName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var officialName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if(item == nil)
        {
            print("item returned nil")
            print(item)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Object did load")
            self.horseName.text = item?.name
            self.officialName.text = item?.offName
            self.imageHolder.image = UIImage(data: (item?.image)!)

            saveEditButton.title = "Edit"
            backCancelButton.title = "To Barn"

            self.deviceImageButton.hidden = true

            self.cameraImageButton.hidden = true

        }

        let tap: UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissEditor")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func dismissEditor()
    {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }



    @IBAction func addImageFromDevice(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func addImageFromCamera(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?)
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        self.imageHolder.image = image
    }



    @IBAction func saveEditTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if(saveEditButton.title == "Save")
        {
            if item != nil
            {
                editItem()

                print("Item edit saved")

                saveEditButton.title = "Edit"
                backCancelButton.title = "To Barn"
            }
            else
            {
                createNewItem()

                print("New item created")

                performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: nil)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            saveEditButton.title = "Save"
            backCancelButton.title = "Cancel"
            print("Not saved")
        }
    }



    func createNewItem()
    {
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

        let item = Item(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

        item.name = horseName.text
        item.offName = officialName.text
        item.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

        do
        {
            try self.moc.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Failed ot create new object")
            return
        }
    }



    func editItem()
    {
        item?.name = horseName.text
        item?.offName = officialName.text
        item!.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)

        do
        {
            try self.moc.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Failed to save item")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the `NSFetchedResultsController` just with the generic initializer is not sufficient.

You have to tell the controller what to do, which managed object context to use, to set the delegate and to perform an initial fetch.

The usual way in Swift is to declare the controller as lazy computed variable.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {

  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
  let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(self.entity, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
  fetchRequest.entity = entity
  fetchRequest.predicate = self.fetchPredicate

  // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
  fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

  // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [self.sortDescriptor]

  // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
  // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
  let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

  do {
    try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
  }

  return aFetchedResultsController
}()
```

Replace all parameters represented by instance variables (starting with `self.`) with your values